# How to set Typeface on ListView which has an ArrayList placed through ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, typeface

I want to set the typeface to the listview in the following code. All the related files are attached.

SearchClient.java

```
Toolbar mToolbar;
EditText search;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
Typeface typeface;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
//Clients List
List<String> client_name = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_client);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search_client);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/ProductSans-Regular.ttf");
    init();

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        }
    });

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Cursor res = databaseHelper.TABLE_CLIENTS_view();
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        client_name.add(res.getString(1));
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.search_list_item, R.id.search_client_name, client_name);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            SearchClient.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}

public void init(){
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_client);
    search.setTypeface(typeface);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_search_client);
}
```

activity_search_client.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/rel_lay_client_search"
    tools:context="com.example.monilandharia.invoice.SearchClient">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_client"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_search" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView_search_client" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

search_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/search_client_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And thanks a lot in advance for help!!

Comment: I think you'll need a custom ArrayAdapter for this.

Comment: refer this.. http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/07/applying-custom-font-in-entire-android.html.

Comment: You cant set listview type face. set type face at your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom textview like below and set the desired typeface in the custom textview class as shown below.

```
    public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ProductSans-Regular.ttf");
            this.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
```

and in your xml (**search_list_item.xml**) file kindly do the following change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.CustomTextView android:id="@+id/search_client_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the type face would be applied to the textview.

Answer (score 0):

1- make a directory `assets` inside the `main` directory

2- download the required typeface from internet and copy the file to the assets

3- in your adapter

```
Typeface name_For_Typeface;

name_For_Typeface= Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
```

textview.setTypeface(name_For_Typeface);

Comment: Yeah, i know it was possible through CustomAdapter but try the one as suggested by @Jeeva Nandhan !! That's cool...

Comment: it was one way to achieve the goal , awesome you find your solution

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks but you made a mistake but I changed it. Check this out:

Your code:

```
    /* Constructor */ public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ProductSans-Regular.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
```

You forgot to call the init() so it didn't make any change. You could have passed the context and attrs in the init like `init(context,attrs)`. Also you could have done as below, instead I did:

```
/* Constructor */ public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ProductSans-Regular.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

Comment: Note that answers are not intended as a device to talk to other answerers. It would be better if you would add feedback via the comments system, which you will be able to do once you have 50 rep points. At a stretch this answer does contain something of your own answer, but it is possible it would not survive a "not an answer" review. Worth bearing in mind for your next answer?